# How to embed Hebrew fonts to a website?

Tags: css, google-app-engine, fonts

I was trying to embed few hebrew fonts to a website.

using this code in my css file :

@font-face
{
    font-family: tamruta;
    src: url('/css/tamruta.eot');
    src: local(tamruta), url('/css/tamruta.ttf') format('opentype');
}

it supposw to work on all browsers.
some how it doesn't work, and I have a massage while trying to upload the application (working with appengine) :

Could not guess mimetype for css/tamruta.ttf.  Using application/octet-stream.
Could not guess mimetype for css/tamruta.eot.  Using application/octet-stream.

Do you have any idea?
or maybe another way to embed fonts to my website.

thanks, arik

Answer (score 1):

Those messages should be warnings and shouldn't be a problem, as there is no official MIME type for OpenType fonts. You should send your EOT files as `application/vnd.ms-fontobject` if possible, though.

Edit: It seems to work just fine for me!

[image]

Comment: it's OK I don't care avout the masseges.

Comment: the problem is I can't see the fonts in other computers, and to be more prices it's different accross browsers.

Comment: Do you have a link to a testing version of the page so I can see what is happening, exactly?

Comment: It is working fine, but in Chrome for example it's not working.

Comment: I can confirm it's not working in Chrome, I get a generic Hebrew font.

Answer (score 0):

.eot is only for IE.

Go to the [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) site, use the @font-face Kit Generator. It will create all the files you need for cross-browser support.